# How to avoid & and % in search

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I am getting query output as all Records when I put `& and %` sign in my search string
I am using oracle and mysql as a database

How I will avoid this , 
this is dynamically generated query snipit using java

```
WHERE 0 = 0 AND (LOWER (business_keywords) LIKE '%&%');
```

and

```
WHERE 0 = 0 AND (LOWER (business_keywords) LIKE '%%%');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape them:

```
SELECT '%' LIKE '%\\%%'
```

You may need to provide your own escape character for this to be portable:

```
LIKE '%!%%' ESCAPE '!'
```

, since `MySQL` treats backslash as a special character while `Oracle` does not.